# How do I pass | (pipe) into python script?

Tags: python, parameters, sys

for example, here is my python script (paramarg.py):
import sys

```
def param(param1, param2, param3):
    print(param1)
    print(param2)
    print(param3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    param(param1=sys.argv[1], param2=sys.argv[2], param3=sys.argv[3])
```

If I execute the python script passing in `1 , 3` it works, but if I try `1 | 3` it does not work:

```
C:\Python>python paramarg.py 1 , 3
1
,
3

C:\Python>python paramarg.py 1 | 3
'3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

C:\Python>

Comment: Trying wrapping it in `"`s.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, this is just basic command syntax. `|` is used for piping between programs, you have to quote it to make it a literal character.

Comment: Your shell thinks you want to run your Python script with the single parameter `1` and send the result of that to another program called `3`, which it cannot find... because you don't have a program called `3`.